# I just installed Loki and "The Panel" has disappeared.

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

I just installed Loki and the "The Panel" at the top of the screen disappeared.

All I've done since I install Loki and before it disappeared is run:

```
sudo apt-get udpate
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and unchecked a few things that were default in the "Dock." I did a little bit of exploring, even clicking on elements in "The Panel" to see what there was to see. I did not change any of the settings. I had Loki installed for less than 30 minutes before this happened.

What did I do to cause this problem? How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge what solved this problem was rebooting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal type `wingpanel`. This will start `wingpanel` process and wingpanel will appear.